# Comma before "...and you will..."

Tags: commas

Please help me understand whether I need to use a comma here or not:

> **Please be patient(,) and you will get everything you want.**

I know the general rules. I see it like this: 2 independent clauses.

> 1. **Please be patient** (independent clause with the null subject - you)
> 2. **And you will get everything you want** (a second independent clause
>    with a subject).

In my opinion, a comma is required, but I am not sure.

Comment: Could you explain what made you think the two clauses were independent? Are you still thinking the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a comma before "and" when it is connecting two independent clauses, but in the case of your example they are not independent.

> Please be patient and you will get everything you want.

"Getting everything you want" is here presented as the result or reward of being patient - they are entirely related. You should therefore omit the comma.

You could present them as independent clauses by using a comma but omitting the conjunction:

> Please be patient, you will get everything you want.

Phrased like this it has a slightly different meaning, namely that the person should be patient *because* they are already certain to get what they want.

Comment: @Astralbee: If you check the link I gave in my answer, you will see that the two sentences are grammatically independent, as each one can stand on its own. But I won't downvote you for that.

Comment: On the link I mentioned I read: 
_The word "and" is a conjunction, and when **a conjunction joins two independent clauses**, you should use a comma with it. The proper place for the comma is before the conjunction.

"On Monday we’ll see the Eiffel Tower, and on Tuesday we’ll visit the Louvre."
The sentence above contains two independent clauses (highlighted in green), so it requires a comma before and. **(By the way, you can tell they’re independent clauses because each one could stand on its own as a complete sentence.)**_

Comment: @fev The grammarly link you cited has some examples that prove you are wrong. "Sam tossed the ball, and watched the dog chase it" is marked as **incorrect** because the two clauses are related - the ball was tossed and the dog chased as a result. In the OP's example the person says that patients will result in getting what they want. If they actually meant them to be independent clauses then there is a better way of writing that, which I have also included in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Grammatically your sentences are indeed independent and this is why they are connected with ***AND***. For this reason, as I have just found out, ***[you do need to use a comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/comma-before-and/#:%7E:text=The%20word%20and%20is%20a,comma%20is%20before%20the%20conjunction.&text=(By%20the%20way%2C%20you%20can,own%20as%20a%20complete%20sentence.))***.

However, meaning wise, your 2 sentences are very much related and their relation could be expressed in this way:

> If you are patient, you will see that you will get everything you want anyway.

Here with or without comma is fine too.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't correct. Commas are not just a "pause", that's just what you learn when you're 6. You don't add a comma in to a sentence at random if you feel like pausing.

Comment: @Astralbee: Alright, will edit my comment. I just realised my mistake, I did a bit of research, I honestly did not know the rule about the comma. In my mother tongue the comma before and is specifically forbidden. sorry to let myself influenced out of ignorance.

Comment: Well that's good that you researched it. You don't have to be a native English speaker to answer questions here, but you do need to be confident and get the answer right. You seem very certain that the two clauses, as presented with a conjunction, are independent - can you please explain why they are independent? Can you explain the use of the conjunction to join two independent clauses? Can you cite your research to show why you can so confidently say they are independent?

Comment: @Astralbee: Believe me, I was confident, because I was not aware of this rule at all, though I am not 6 years old. So I am grateful to you for learning something new. I did explain about the conjunction in my comment to your answer.

Comment: Did you not know that conjunctions can be subordinating, but also [_**coordinating**_](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/coordinating-conjunctions/#:~:text=A%20coordinating%20conjunction%20is%20a,or%2C%20yet%2C%20and%20so.), which I believe is the case here?

Comment: Yes I do know that. Did you know that not one of the examples on the page you just linked to has a comma after the conjunction? So why do you use this as proof of needing a comma?

Comment: What kind of conjunction is "and"?

Comment: You may want to read [this discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/554464/can-and-ever-be-a-subordinating-conjunction/554479?noredirect=1#comment1365959_554479) about the subject.